# equivalent of curl -k option in axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, curl, axios

Is there an equivalent of `curl -k` option in axios? when i am calling api with `curl -k` it is working perfectly fine but if i am using it via axios code in node js it gives ssl chain certificate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a HTTPS agent to ignore SSL errors like so:

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});
```